# PHP Ajax saving multiple textareas without exiting page

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, textarea

I've got a set of textareas below. all the textareas have the same name "comment" I have a button for each textarea and the button and text area are each grouped into a divs called user1, user2 etc. When i click the button for user1 i would like to send the comment using ajax to a PHP file called `save.php` with the get string user=user1 or user2 and comment= the comment posted. If successful i would then like the hide the text area and button for that user and just display the comment that was written.

```
<div id="user1">
  <textarea cols="40" rows="5" name="comment">User 1 Comment</textarea>
  <button>Save User 1 Comment</button>
</div>

<br><br>

<div id="user2">
  <textarea cols="40" rows="5" name="comment">User 2 Comment</textarea>
  <button>Save User 2 Comment</button>
</div>

<br><br>

<div id="user3">
  <textarea cols="40" rows="5" name="comment">User 3 Comment</textarea>
  <button>Save User 3 Comment</button>
</div>
```

Any ideas how I can do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, check the following lines of script-

```
$.post(
      "addcomment.php",
      $("form#addComment").serialize(), 
          function( data ) {
              $( "#show" ).html( data );
          }
);
```

Let me describe little about above code-

1. $ = Dollar sign for jQuery or instead of word `jQuery`
2. "addcomment.php" is the proccessing page where comment insert will perform and send back the data to show.
3. `$("form#addComment").serialize()` will take the user input and it will be ready to form submit. 
   a. Here `form#addComment` is the form of your comment textarea.
4. `function ( data )` is the return result of your query included in `addcomment.php` file
5. And finally, `$( "#show" ).html( data )`. `#show` is an HTML element ID where you would like to load the result (comment) in your page

> ***N.B.*** To do this `Ajax` code you need to include `jQuery` API under your `<head>` tag of your script file.

If you understand above form serializing process, you will able to perform this for multiple form submission too.